# How to check the occurrence of the words in the SQL of a sentence using PHP and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm getting a sentence from user input then chopping it into words and listing them in a array.

After that I want to pass this array depending on number of words in the sentence to a SQL query which will check for the occurrence of each word separately and return then number.

The first part is done by using regex:

```
preg_match_all('/<[^>]++>|[^<>\s]++/', $sent, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

The output is like this:

[image]

But for the SQL query loop I'm stuck.  I don't know where to start with my database table is like this:

[image]

And my expected output is something like:

[image]

P.S.:- I think the PHP code should know the length of the user input sentence first, then tokenize it to pass the words to the SQL loop  query to be searched separately.

Comment: `SELECT word, COUNT(word) as freq FROM tbl_words WHERE word IN ("hi", "how", "are", "you")`?

Comment: @Justinas the sentence will be difference each time a user will inter a different one so it  should be a loop not me typing the words one by one in the query

Comment: and when the word does not exist in the database it should return 0

Comment: Get separate words in PHP, add them to `IN` condition, back in PHP loop words and check if it exists in returned set, if yes - use info, if not - add 0

Comment: that is not consistent it should add the words into php automatically rather than me doing it my self then go to database to check.

Comment: It's not clear what frequency means in this context. Do you mean that if the first user types "Hey there", then "Hey" and "there" both show 1. However, if the second user types "Hey you", then "Hey" would be 2, while "you" would be 1 still?

Comment: the frequency is the number of times that word appeared  in my dataset, like if the user typed Hey There, the frequency of Hey and there shoud be 0 as they did not appear in my dataset frequency  table. but for the word "hey alin" they " hey "word should be 0 and the :alin "name should be "1"

Comment: @Justinas - You are almost there -- Now tell the Op to construct that query in PHP.  Also use `COUNT(*)` and add `GROUP BY word`.  (Meanwhile, don't worry about dup words; they will be culled by MySQL.)

Comment: can you post the answer you are thinking about please ? @RickJames

Comment: So "hi how are you" should return the current count/freq of the words [hi = 0, how = 5, etc] and then update the count on the db or update the db and then return the count of each word in "hi how are you" [hi =1, how = 6, are = 6you = 1, etc]?

Comment: No it will not update it will just return the first as you said hi = 0 how =5 etc the words that does not exist will always be zero

Comment: `$wordList = array("hi", "how", "are", "you");`

`$wordListString = implode(',',$wordList);`


`SELECT word,  freq FROM table_words WHERE word IN ($wordListString); `


Execute above query and you will get keywords which exist in the DB so you can use the freq column value for them and for the rest of the keywords, you can use default value 0 as this doesn't exist in DB

Comment: can you post it as a proper answer please ? @VivekD. and the word list depends on the user input so the sentence will change every time, and the list will never be the same so the list should be updated based on the user input

Comment: @programmingfreak I have added a full set of code that you might be able to replicate on your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'll explain the code stepwise.

```
<?php
    $sentence = '';
    $result = '';

    if (isset($_GET['sentence'])) {
        $sentence = $_GET['sentence'];
        $tokens = tokenize($sentence);

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
        $sql = getSQL($tokens, $mysqli);
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    }

    function tokenize($sent) {
        preg_match_all('/<[^>]++>|[^<>\s]++/', $sent, $tokens);
        return $tokens[0];
    }

    function getSQL($tokens, $mysqli) {
        $sql = array();
        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            $sql[] = sprintf("select '%s', ifnull(min(freq), 0) from test where word = '%s' ",
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($token),
                $mysqli->real_escape_string($token)
            );
        }
        return implode(' union all ', $sql);
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<form method="get">
sentence: <input type="text" name="sentence" value="<?php echo $sentence; ?>"/>
</form>

<?php
if ($result !== ''):
?>

<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>word</th>
            <th>freq</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()):
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
    </table>

<?php
endif;
?>

</div>
</form>
```

## PHP code above the HTML code

We set the `sentence` and `result` variable to empty. We'll store what the user typed into the variable sentence. The result will be the result from MySQL.

`if (isset($_GET['sentence'])) { ... }` block checks whether the webpage had query string named `sentence`. If we received that query string, then do something. Otherwise don't do anything.

In that block, we sequentially do this:

- store sentence supplied by the user in a variable
- use your preg_match_all method to tokenize the sentence
- create a SQL dynamically
- execute the the SQL and store the output in results variable

The `function tokenize` is self-explanatory. It takes the sentence and outputs an array just like you noticed.

### SQL creation

You can ask MySQL for frequency like so

```
select freq from test where word = 'bogus';
```

If the word 'hi' is not present, you will get no results. In order to force a result, you can ask for a summary like count, min, max, etc.

```
select min(freq) from test where word = 'bogus';
```

will result

```
+-----------+
| min(freq) |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
```

If we asked MySQL to substitute NULL with zero like this:

```
select ifnull(min(freq), 0) from test where word = 'bogus';
```

you'll get:

```
+----------------------+
| ifnull(min(freq), 0) |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
```

So, we'll take advantage of that and ask:

```
select 'hi', ifnull(min(freq), 0) from test where word = 'hi';
```

If 'hi' doesn't exist, you'll get

```
+----+----------------------+
| hi | ifnull(min(freq), 0) |
+----+----------------------+
| hi |                    0 |
+----+----------------------+
```

Now, you could combine multiple queries like this:

```
select 'hi', ifnull(min(freq), 0) from test where word = 'hi'
union all
select 'how', ifnull(min(freq), 0) from test where word = 'how';
```

to get

```
+-----+----------------------+
| hi  | ifnull(min(freq), 0) |
+-----+----------------------+
| hi  |                    0 |
| how |                    5 |
+-----+----------------------+
```

Great. So, let's try taking all the tokens and create a `UNION ALL` query.

That's what `function getSQL` does. It goes through each token and stores each `select ...` query in the array.

Notice that I use `real_escape_string` functionality within mysqli to escape special characters and make the query safer.

Then, we join all the select queries together and put `union all` between them using the `implode` function.

Once we receive the query back, we execute it using `$mysqli->execute($sql)`. That returns for us the results.

## HTML part

We create a form with a GET method so that sentence is returned as a query string. If it is the first time the page is loaded, `$sentence` will be empty. We publish that in the `value` attribute. If the page was called with query string, `$sentence` will contain what the user typed.

```
<form method="get">
sentence: <input type="text" name="sentence" value="<?php echo $sentence; ?>"/>
</form>
```

Then,

```
<?php
if ($result !== ''):
?>

<div>
...
</div>

<?php
endif;
?>
```

The  will be published only if `$result` is not an empty string. `$result` is empty when the page loads (or query fails). So, that block will not be visible. If the query succeeds, `$result` will not be empty and that block will be visible.

## Table creation

We create the table and put inline PHP. We loop through the records one by one and publish the token and the frequency. As previously noted, those words that don't have a frequency will show zero.

Try it out. Also note that there are several other improvements that can be done to this code, but it's a start.

Comment: best answer best explanation nothing more to say thanks man you made my day

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = array();
while (...) {
    $word = ...;  // extract the word
    $words[] = "'$word'";
}
$in_list = implode(', ', $words);  //  'hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'
$sql = "SELECT  word,
                COUNT(*) as freq   -- COUNT(*) is the common syntax
            FROM tbl_words 
            WHERE word IN ($in_list)";
... $sql ...   // perform the query and deal with the results
```

To do the update, generate this and execute:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_words
            SET freq = freq + 1
            WHERE word IN ($in_list)";
```

If a sentence can have a word twice, do you want the table to incremented twice?  Whether or not you want that, I might build a hash instead of an array:

```
$words = array();
while (...) {
    $word = ...;  // extract the word
    $words[$word] = (isset($words[$word]) ? $words[$word] + 1 : 1);
}
$in_list = implode(', ', array_keys($words));  //  'hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'
```

That assumes multiple copies of a word count as only 1.

For the incrementing by the repeated count, things get messier.

Based on your parsing code:

```
$words = array();
preg_match_all('/<[^>]++>|[^<>\s]++/', $sent, $tokens);
foreach($tokens as $token) {
    $words[$word] = (isset($words[$word]) ? $words[$word] + 1 : 1);
}
$in_list = implode(', ', array_keys($words));
echo $in_list;
```

Comment: @programmingfreak - The while(...) and $word=... need to be replaced by your code to split the sentence into "words".

Comment: I don’t understand can you show me whatcyou mean please where shall I place the code

Comment: I added another example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll give it a shot and please tell me if it's not what you're asking for (English isn't my first language).

## PHP

```php
<?php
// Connects to DB
$conn = mysqli_connect ( 'server', 'username', 'password', 'db');

if ( isset ( $_GET['sentence'] ) ) {

  // Sets the table var
  $table = "";

  // Prevents SQL Injection
  $sentence = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn, $_GET['sentence'] );

  // Splits the sentence inputted by the user into an array of individual words
  $wordArr = explode (  " ", $sentence );

  // For loop to execute the SQL Query for each word
  for ( $x = 0; $x < count ( $wordArr ); $x++ ) {

    $word = $wordArr[$x];

    // SQL Query to information about the word (if it exists in the table) from DB
    $sqlFindWord = "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `word` = '$word'";

    // Executes the query
    $resultFindWord = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sqlFindWord );

    $resultFindWord = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $resultFindWord );

    // If the word exists in the table...
    if ( $resultFindWord ) {

      $frequency = $resultFindWord['freq'] + 1;

      // SQL Query adds 1 to the word's frequency in the table
      $sqlUpdateFrequency = "UPDATE `words` SET `freq` = $frequency WHERE `word` = $word";

      // Executes SQL Query
      $resultUpdateFrequency = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sqlUpdateFrequency );

      // Adds word to HTML table
      $table .= "<tr><td>" . $word . "</td><td>" . $frequency . "</td></tr>";

    } else {

      // Word doesn't exist in the table, so it must be added with a frequency of 1
      $sqlAddWord = "INSERT INTO `words` (`word`, `freq`) VALUES ('$word', 1)";

      // Executes the query
      $resultAddWord = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sqlAddWord );

      // Adds word to the HTML table
      $table .= "<tr><td>" . $word . "</td><td>1</td></tr>";

    }
  }
}
?>
```

## HTML

```html
<form action="#" method="GET" validate="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter A Sentence" name="sentence" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Sentence" />
</form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Word</th>
    <th>Freq</th>
  </tr>
  <?php echo $table; ?>
</table>
```

If you have any questions about *any* part of the code, or if I misunderstood the question please tell me.